# Regex pattern matching cursor-position

Tags: regular-expression, cursor

Considering the following regex pattern:

```
/\s*<<.\{-}>>/
```

I want to match those patterns *only when the cursor is somewhere on this pattern*.

So, if have the line (the character enclosed in [] is the cusor position):

```
This is <<on[e]>> and this is <<another one>>.
```

I want to only match `<<one>>`, not `<<another one>>`.

I know that `\%#` specifies the cursor position, but I don't know how to apply it to state that *the cursor may be anywhere on that pattern*.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you still want to match if the cursor is in the whitespace before the `<<`?

Comment: @Rich Yes. That is not the most important aspect, I could live with it if that would be missing. But it should match on any other position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use a lookahead before the regex and a lookbehind after the regex. That ensures the cursor is *after* the start of the match, and *before* the end of the match.

One issue with the regex you're using is `.\{-}` which is a non-greedy operator. If you add anchors for the cursor position, this will end up matching from the beginning of `<<one` to the end of `another one>>`. To solve that, I'm replacing it with `\([^>]\|>[^>]\)*`, which will match any character other than `>`, or a single `>` followed by a different character. (Perhaps a negative match would have worked here instead.)

Putting it all together:

```
/\(.*\%#\)\@=\s*<<\([^>]\|>[^>]\)*>>\(\%#.*\)\@<=
```

**UPDATE:** Using [`\@>`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3E) for the middle bit is able to preserve the `-\{-}`, resulting in:

```
 /\(.*\%#\)\@=\(\s*<<.\{-}>>\)\@>\(\%#.*\)\@<=
```

Comment: Wow, this gets way more complicated than I had expected. But thank you. I think I will try your approach in the answer, although the one in your comment works as well. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah it gets complicated! I just updated the answer to incorporate the comment. Glad this helped you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the atom [/\&](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/branch). This is like forcing two different regular atoms to match at the same position.

Now it becomes a bit complicated, since the cursor position can be anywhere inside the `<<..>>` and then you also want to allow whitespace inside those `<<..>>`. This makes it a bit complex to match the correct item if there are several matches in a line.

So instead of using `.\{-\}` to allow an arbitrarily long number of matches (even other `<<`), you need to restrict your match to only match until the `>>`.

To make the pattern simpler, let's for now assume all characters are allowed except for `>`. That would make the pattern like this:

```
/<[^>]\+>>\&[^>]*\%#[^>]*>>
```

which means `<` followed by any character except `>` (`[^>]`) and at the same time (`\&`) allow any character except `>`, followed by the cursor position (`\%#`), followed by any character except `>` followed by >>.

Now you can make this more complicated by enforcing the `>>` delimiter. Possible search patterns are `\(>>\)\@!` (not followed by `>>`) or the already mentioned `\([^>]\|>[^>]\)`. However this will make your search pattern a lot more complex, so this is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

You might also want to have a look at the distributed plugin [LogiPat](https://vimhelp.org/pi_logipat.txt.html), which allows to construct patterns using logical operators (and, or, not, etc).

Comment: Thank you. Although I have accepted filbrandens answer, your approach works, too. Unfortunately, both can get quite complicated. :-) But ok, I have to live with that.